# Hibernate Search Indexing Speed Decreasing

Tags: java, spring-boot, lucene, hibernate-search, full-text-indexing

I am having two Entities in my Code and DB. one Entity is having 0.2 Million Records and the other one is having 2.6 Million Records.
I am using MassIndexer StartandWait() Method and Start() Method. When I start to Index my Entity with Less records i.e, 0.2 million it indexes them fairly quick at a constant Speed Documents/Second but when it starts indexing the other Entity with 2.6 million records the Indexing Speed decreases by miles within minutes and CPU Consumption on my windows show 100 % and Memory also show 100% the speed drops 2000 Documents/second to 8 Documents/second and never looks like it will finish.

this is my code

```
    try
    {
        logger.info("Indexing Started============================");
        SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor();
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
        MassIndexer massIndexer = fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer()
        .purgeAllOnStart(purgeAllOnStart)
        .progressMonitor(progressMonitor)
        .typesToIndexInParallel(typesToIndexInParallel)
        .batchSizeToLoadObjects(batchSizeToLoadObjects)
        .threadsForSubsequentFetching(8)
        .idFetchSize(idFetchSize)
        .threadsToLoadObjects(threadsToLoadObjects)
        .cacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);

        try {
          if (!async) {
            massIndexer.startAndWait();
          } else {
            massIndexer.start();
          }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          logger.error("mass reindexing interrupted: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            fullTextEntityManager.flushToIndexes();
        }
       
        logger.info("Indexing completed============================");
    }       catch(Exception e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        
    }
```

See if I can get this fixed and indexed on constant speed and is there any issue with Memory and CPU Usage overtime, so whats could be the fix and way around?

How can I avoid this thing without getting the indexing speed decreased?

Comment: For future reference, this was submitted as a bug report and is being discussed here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-4010